# Sqlite database with release version of Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I currently have a release version of my Qt desktop app.
I have used Sqlite database in the application. How can i give the database file with the 
app? so that when the application is used then the database can be accessed and used?

Comment: If you have GUI, you can use a dialog, or you can provide the database name as a command line argument to your application.

Comment: Take a look at this posts accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254250/embedded-database-in-qt

Comment: ReadWrite, or read-only?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by this, how one can open /create or access database in qt, then you should use [QSqlDatabase](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqldatabase.html) class, here is an example though:

```
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>
#include <QtSql/QSqlError>

QSqlDatabase db;
QSqlQuery query;
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("db.sqlite"); // path to your database
qDebug()<<"database is opened - "<<db.open();
// this is how you can execute queries to database
query.exec("create table options "
                      "(id integer primary key, "
                      "option text)");

query.exec(QString("insert into options values(NULL,'%1')").arg(QString("look")));
query.exec(QString("insert into options values(NULL,'%1')").arg(QString("dance")));
query.exec(QString("insert into options values(NULL,'%1')").arg(QString("read")));
db.close();
```

and in your .pro file don't forget to add `QT += sql` line